# python request.post, post a user comment to the server

Tags: python

Using python, how would you post a comment that the user types to the host server? If the server is expecting a parameter named usercomment, what would the request.post line look like to post the comment to the host? The code that I have does not correctly post the comment so when I try to display the list of comments I get a status of 500.

```
def usercomment (host, usercomment)
    postcomment=request.post(host, input(additional_arg), 
    allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: what is payload type the server is expecting ?

Comment: the user should be able to type "this is a comment" in normal characters

Comment: what are the python that are used here and usually all request to the server is of specific content-type

Comment: add some information about the response from the server. Have you tried invoking the rest service directly from post man ?.